# "sshpass is not recognized" on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, sshpass

I want to run `sshpass` command from my Windows to remote Linux server. I use this command:

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh ldap.nextstep4it.com -l root -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

But my cmd return below error statement:

> 'sshpass' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

I think this is because Windows don't have `sshpass` package as Linux do. From Linux I have to install `sshpass` package to be able to run this command.

Is there anybody know how to run `sshpass` command through Windows command line?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You cant run sshpass in windows.
You can however use putty via the windows command line, to achieve the same thing.

```
putty -load "host" -l username -pw password
```

Also you can upload files via command line (with a password) using WinSCP

```
winscp /command "option batch abort" "option confirm off" "open sftp://user:password@example.com/" "put examplefile.txt /home/user/" "exit"
```

Comment: what should I use as winscp? For example the path to winscp.exe?

Comment: It's opening a "Putty Configuration" window for me. I am currently on git bash. I also tried the command via windows command prompt and powershell. It always opens a "Putty Configuration" as if it was invoked without arguments. What's the issue here?

Comment: `putty -ssh hostname -l username -pw password`  
  
This works better, in a way that it opens another terminal window and auto logs in to the server.   
  
Is there any way to make this even better by asking it to not open another window and just login within git bash?

Comment: `plink -ssh hostname -l username -pw password` This is best. Opens within my git bash terminal and auto logs in. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 14):

Instead of OpenSSH `ssh`, you can use [PuTTY `plink`](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html). It's command line equivalent of PuTTY and has very similar command-line syntax as OpenSSH `ssh`. But on top of it, it has [`-pw` switch](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-pw) for providing a password (there's also `-pwfile` switch).

The `plink` equivalent of your `ssh` call is:

```
plink ldap.nextstep4it.com -l root -pw password
```

---

You absolutely should not use `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` to blindly accept all host keys. That is a security flaw. You lose a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). Instead, with `plink`, you can use `-hostkey` switch to set the fingerprint of the expected host key.

---

Similarly:

- instead of OpenSSH `scp`, use [PuTTY `pscp`](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter5.html);
- instead of OpenSSH `sftp`, use [PuTTY `psftp`](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter6.html).

Both have the `-pw` and `-pwfile` switches.

Alternatively, both for SCP and SFTP, you can use *my* [WinSCP SFTP/SCP client](https://winscp.net). WinSCP also supports providing the password on command-line/in script. And there's a guide for [converting OpenSSH `sftp` script to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_psftp_script_to_winscp).

---

No matter, if you use OpenSSH, PuTTY or WinSCP, it is always better is to use public key authentication than the password.

Comment: easiest solution thanks

Answer (score 7):

Using *Windows Subsystem for Linux* (`WSL`); first go to `Settings`->`Turn Windows Features On or Off`->`Enable Windows Subsystem for Linux`, then download and install [Ubuntu](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6) or another Linux from the `Microsoft Store`.

To access WSL from `cmd.exe` type `bash` or `wsl`

```
sudo apt-get install sshpass

sshpass -p passxxxx ssh user@ip.address 'touch newfileonserver.txt'
```

To invoke from a windows environment, eg. `cmd.exe` or `Process.Start()`

```
bash -c "sshpass -p passxxxx ssh user@ip.address 'touch newfileonserver.txt' "
```

Comment: Yeah, and the command will be: `wsl -- sshpass ...`

Answer (score 4):

You can install QtdSync for Windows.

This will contain the sshpass.exe

Comment: This did not work for me, there was still a password prompt even when I supplied the password using the `-p` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Just install cygwin in your Windows, then download sshpass and compile/install it, the whole process is quick and easy, it works great in my environment.

Comment: 30 minutes to install make & gcc and run the installation. Thanks :)

Comment: What happens if u dont have gcc and not easy to install, cant believe this binary is so difficult to find

Answer (score -4):

You can rather try `putty`.

Download it from [here](http://www.putty.org)

Or you can install cygwin and install sshpass, but that would be a larger task.

So, if you need a passwordless login then with putty you can use puttygen, which you can install from the same link provided above.

Comment: thank you for the answer Jord, but it did not solve my question. what i am trying to do is to run sshpass package into windows command prompt. i appreciate your answer by the way