# What program can I use like sshpass on Unix to pass my ssh password to git clone?

Tags: windows, git, ssh

I am writing a windows batch file that clones some repos. I have an ssh password set and need to pass it to git clone for this batch file.

On a unix OS I can use sshpass and pass it the password and the command I want to run...

```
sshpass -p password git clone ssh://user@address/path
```

Is there a way I can do something similar in a windows batch file?

Comment: If you are an overzealous mod, please actually check if an issue is a real duplicate, and not just contains similar words. TY! :)

Comment: The recommended approach for non-interactive use is SSH keys, which will work here without any additional tools.

Comment: @bk2204 This is not the case because I am using ssh keys. But my ssh key requires a password. So it does require additional tools.

Comment: Then add it to an agent so you can use it without the password.  That will prompt you only once, when you add it to the agent.  When you're done, you can kill the agent or just leave it.

Comment: It's possible to remove the passphrase from an ssh key. If you're willing to store your password in plain text so that a program like sshpass can use it, using an ssh key without a passphrase won't be any more of a risk.

Answer (score 4):

Normally, as explained in [GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent), you add your SSH key to the ssh-agent.

You can [automate the start of the SSH agent](https://gist.github.com/adojos/5aab5e1dcedc16957c465be0212ea099), but you will still at some point enter the password, since there is no sshpass on Windows.
Only [`plink` has a `-pw` option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64108006/6309).